# Using CType to single with VB.net returns extra digit

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB.NET 2010. I ran into an issue that at first I thought was a database issue since the value was being pulled from a DB2 table. However, it appears to be in .NET itself. I determined this by running the following two lines of code:

```
    Dim sAmount As Single
    sAmount = CType("212639.04", Single)
```

When I then look at sAmount, the value is 212639.047.

My question: Where is the 7 coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is you're using Single which is a floating-pont data type, which doesn't work well with fractions that aren't binary fractions.

[Floating-Point Expressions Do Not Compare as Equal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae382yt8.aspx)

> When you work with floating-point numbers (Single Data Type (Visual
>   Basic) and Double Data Type (Visual Basic)), remember that they are
>   stored as binary fractions. This means they cannot hold an exact
>   representation of any quantity that is not a binary fraction (of the
>   form k / (2 ^ n) where k and n are integers). For example, 0.5 (= 1/2)
>   and 0.3125 (= 5/16) can be held as precise values, whereas 0.2 (= 1/5)
>   and 0.3 (= 3/10) can be only approximations.
>
> Because of this imprecision, you cannot rely on exact results when you
>   operate on floating-point values. In particular, two values that are
>   theoretically equal might have slightly different representations.
>
> To compare floating-point quantities
>
> ```
> Calculate the absolute value of their difference by using the Abs method of the 
> Math class in the System namespace.
>
> Determine an acceptable maximum difference, such that you can consider the two 
> quantities to be equal for practical purposes if their difference is no larger.
>
> Compare the absolute value of the difference to the acceptable difference.
> ```

Alternatively double will return a number with greater precision.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I inherited someone else code. Thankfully it is just a display issue and not the actual value that is stored.

Comment: In case you didn't see my edit.  Using double fixes your immediate issue.